# How To Bind() With Dynamically Created Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

I'm having issues rebinding something with a dynamically created object, from prepend. I;ve tried many things but I'm able to unbind only. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".newdir").click(function(){
    $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-dir'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nd-text' type='text'></div></div>");
    $(".newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity",".35");
    $(".newdir, .newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").unbind();      
});

$(".ribbon-menu").on("click", ".newfile", function(){
    $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-fn'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nf-text' type='text'></div></div>");
    $(".newdir, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity",".35");
    $(".ribbon-menu").unbind(); 
});

$("div.d-exp").on("click", ".exp-x", function(){        
    $(".ribbon-menu").bind();   
    $(".newdir, .newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity","1");    
    $("div#new.fm-dir, div#new.fm-fn").remove();
});

});
```

LIVE ANSWER http://jsfiddle.net/dC344/

Comment: What version jquery? Bind() is deprecated. What are you trying to bind?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".newdir", function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to bind it back, you need to specify which event and the handler function

In this case since you want to fire the click handler only once you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.unbind(),](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) also use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to unbind handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".newdir").click(function () {
        $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-dir'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nd-text' type='text'></div></div>");
        $(".newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", ".35");
        $(".newdir, .newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").unbind();
    });

    function addRibbonMenuHandler() {
        $(".ribbon-menu").one("click", ".newfile", function () {
            $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-fn'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nf-text' type='text'></div></div>");
            $(".newdir, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", ".35");
        });
    }

    addRibbonMenuHandler();

    $("div.d-exp").on("click", ".exp-x", function () {
        addRibbonMenuHandler();
        $(".newdir, .newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", "1");
        $("div#new.fm-dir, div#new.fm-fn").remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: So far this is the best comment but it doesnt really work. Ima try to to make a jsfiddle for the visual help. But im trying to mimic file browser event behaviors. When new file or new dir is clicked, all other buttons should unbind, and bind back when task finished.

Comment: @TimBanon if you can share the markup in a fiddle it will be great

Answer (score 0):

Before Jquery support `live()` to bind event to selectors, but after `Jquery 1.7` , `live` is deprecated. Now , you can use `delegate` or `on` to bind event to selectors ( as in `Jquery Document` )

However, I usually bind function after creating object , like as

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $("#main").click(function(){
      $("#main").append("<div class="new-div">Add new DIV</div>"); // Add new div in main
      $(".new-div").on("click",doBindEvent); // Add click event into new div which function you defined
   });
});

function doBindEvent(){
   // Do anything you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Arun P Johnny, I was able to modify the script with some logic that solved my problem. I'm a novice when it comes jQuery, although it can piece it together very well after research ... XD

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function addRibbonMenuHandler1() {
    $(".ribbon-menu").on("click", ".newdir", function () {
        $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-dir'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nd-text' type='text'></div></div>");
        $(".newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", ".35");
        $(".ribbon-menu").unbind();
    });
}

function addRibbonMenuHandler2() {
    $(".ribbon-menu").on("click", ".newfile", function () {
        $(".d-exp").prepend("<div id='new' class='fm-fn'><div class='exp-x'></div><div class='fm-name'><input class='nf-text' type='text'></div></div>");
        $(".newdir, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", ".35");
        $(".ribbon-menu").unbind();
    });
}

addRibbonMenuHandler1(); 
addRibbonMenuHandler2();

$("div.d-exp").on("click", ".exp-x", function () {
    addRibbonMenuHandler1();
    addRibbonMenuHandler2();
    $(".newdir, .newfile, .paste, .copy, .cut, .rename, .delete, .fileinfo, .visit").css("opacity", "1");
    $("div#new.fm-dir, div#new.fm-fn").remove();
    $(".ribbon-menu").bind();
});

});
```

Comment: as I said don't use unbind ... use .off('click')